# Changing date format using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am getting date in the format (YY/DD/MM) for ex 2010/12/07
i want to change format to Monday 7 July, 2010 through javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`toLocaleDateString()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp) method of the [date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object (*it will be specific to the user's locale*)

```
var d = new Date('2010/12/07');
alert(d.toLocaleDateString());
```